Definition of Adapted Orthonormal Frame on Differential Geometry
In my book of Differential Geometry it is mentioned that every generalized helix $\alpha: I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ can be presented on adapted orthonormal frame as $\alpha (s) = (\alpha_1 (s) , \alpha_2 (s) , b s)$ for some $b \in \Bbb{R}$ .
Despite, the book does not defined what is that Adapted orthonormal frame and when I search about it on internet only find complicated definitions applied to Differential Topology that I cannot see how it works here. First I thought that it refers to Frenet Frame since it is an orthonormal frame but if I am not wrong on Frenet coordinates $\alpha = 0$ , so I getting more confused and it would be very helpful it someone could provide a simple definition and explanation on this case.
ADD-ON
Since $\alpha$ is generalized helix, there is some unit vector $w \in \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $\forall s \in I : \langle N_\alpha (s) , w \rangle = 0$, which implies that $\langle \alpha (s) , w \rangle = bs$ for some $b \in \Bbb{R}$ . Now, let $v \in \Bbb{R}$ unit vector orthogonal to $w$ and $u := v \times w$ . Then $\{ u , v , w\}$ is an orthonormal system and then a basis of $\Bbb{R}^3$ in which coordinates $\alpha (s)= (\alpha_1 (s), \alpha_2 (s), bs)$ .
If we define $\tilde{\alpha}(s) = (\alpha_1(s) , \alpha_2(s))$ , is there any relation between $\kappa_\alpha $ and $\kappa_{\tilde{\alpha}}$ ? I am wondering this since I think it would be useful on other situations.

Which book is this? Is the curve assumed to lie in a surface?

No, to use the Frenet frame, you would write $\alpha=\lambda T + \mu N + \nu B$ for some functions $\lambda,\mu,\nu$. The sentence is misleading (perhaps a language issue?) — they mean an appropriate choice of orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$. The axis of the generalized cylinder on which the helix lies will be vertical. Yes, what text is this? This is your second post in two days about it.

@Deane No, it does not lie in a surface, or at least it does not say anything about it. The book is 'Geometría elemental sobre curvas y superficies' of J.J. Pardo.

@TedShifrin I see, my mistake then. I thought it was $0$ since imagining the Frenet Frame in my head $\alpha$ was at the "origin" . Yes, the book (I put the title in the above comment) is more troubling than helping, I think I will change it for other at the library.

Since this text is at the undergraduate level, try my text, freely available at the link in my profile. I think the exposition is relatively clear and there are plenty of exercises, ranging from easy computations to quite challenging.
